# cascading with ravendb using Cascading Deletion Bundle

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have a raven driven application and I am trying to implement Cascading Deletion Bundle. The setup seems pretty simple, but the mapping setup portion is a little unclear to me from their 1 document about cascading. Anyway here is my setup, thanks for any help.

```
// An album class with no reference to photos
class Album
{
    public string Id { get; set; } //ID for album from raven
}

// A photo class with a reference to its parent album
class Photo
{
    public string Id { get; set; } //ID for photo from raven
    public string PhotoName { get; set; }
    public Album PhotoAlbum  { get; set; }
}

// On album store 
session.Store(album);
session.Advanced.GetMetadataFor(album)["Raven-Cascade-Delete-Documents"] =
    RavenJToken.FromObject(new[] { album.Id });

// THIS DOES NOT WORK, But I was assuming that it would search for each document
// with a reference to an album and delete it.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when modeling references between documents, you need to reference the foreign document key, not the entire document.  What you have now will embed the album in the document.  Do this instead:

```
public class Photo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PhotoName { get; set; }
    public string AlbumId { get; set; }
}
```

Regarding cascading delete, the bundle simply looks at the metadata when deleting the document and deletes any documents referenced.  It does *not* help you build up that list of documents to begin with.  You have to do that yourself.  Every time you add a photo, you would load the album and add the photo's Id to the album's cascading deletion list.

So when saving the album and first few photos:

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var album = new Album();
    session.Store(album);

    var photoA = new Photo { PhotoName = "A", AlbumId = album.Id };
    var photoB = new Photo { PhotoName = "B", AlbumId = album.Id };
    var photoC = new Photo { PhotoName = "C", AlbumId = album.Id };
    session.Store(photoA);
    session.Store(photoB);
    session.Store(photoC);

    session.Advanced.AddCascadeDeleteReference(album,
                                               photoA.Id,
                                               photoB.Id,
                                               photoC.Id);

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then later, adding a photo to an existing album

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    // you would know this already at this stage
    const string albumId = "albums/1";

    var photoD = new Photo { PhotoName = "D", AlbumId = albumId };
    session.Store(photoD);

    var album = session.Load<Album>(albumId);
    session.Advanced.AddCascadeDeleteReference(album, photoD.Id);

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is the `AddCascadeDeleteReference` extension method I used above.  You could do it yourself, but this makes things a bit easier.  Put it in a static class.

```
public static void AddCascadeDeleteReference(
  this IAdvancedDocumentSessionOperations session,
  object entity, params string[] documentKeys)
{
    var metadata = session.GetMetadataFor(entity);
    if (metadata == null)
      throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "The entity must be tracked in the session before calling this method.");

    if (documentKeys.Length == 0)
      throw new ArgumentException(
        "At least one document key must be specified.");

    const string metadataKey = "Raven-Cascade-Delete-Documents";

    RavenJToken token;
    if (!metadata.TryGetValue(metadataKey, out token))
        token = new RavenJArray();

    var list = (RavenJArray) token;
    foreach (var documentKey in documentKeys.Where(key => !list.Contains(key)))
        list.Add(documentKey);

    metadata[metadataKey] = list;
}
```

Comment: I also added that extension method to the [Raven.Contrib project](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb.contrib) for posterity.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, this did not work for me. On this project I am adding photos after the album is created. So Im adding to and existing album like in your example. When I save a photo, the metadata is not there on the existing album document? Do I have to create a empty metadata list on the album create? Is that even my problem. I followed everything from ravens documentation, your documentation. Not sure whats going on here

Comment: The metadata just does not save on SaveChanges() when I am creating a photo document.

Comment: If you are using the extension method I gave you, it creates the list for you if it doesn't exist.  What version are you using?  I tested on both 1.0.992 and 2.0.2190 and it works.  Changes to metadata are indeed picked up on savechanges.

Comment: Also, are you properly disposing your session after saving changes?  It should be in a using block.

Comment: Yes, I am properly disposing the session using the "using" block. And I am on version 2. Im not saying your method is not correct because I debugged through it and looks like it does add, but when it comes time to saving it to the server nothing is happening.

Comment: Matt, There is a bug in Raven, I was successfully able to update the matadata only if I changed one of the properties and then SaveChanges(). Before I was storing the photo, then changing the metadata on the album (not any properties). Another issue I am having now, is that its not actually cascading the photo document when the album is deleted. Here is the setting in the metadata.  "Raven-Cascade-Delete-Documents": [
    "Photos/161"
  ]
I delete the album and the photo remains.